# Path of a command

Tags: path, solaris

Could someone please let me know how to get to know the executable path of a command/utility in solaris?? like executable path of ls is /usr/bin

Answer (score 7):

use `type` command

For example

```
[max@localhost ~]$ type cal
cal is /usr/bin/cal
[max@localhost ~]$ type ifconfig
ifconfig is /sbin/ifconfig
[max@localhost ~]$ type ping
ping is /bin/ping
```

Comment: `type -P` will give you the pure path in a more easily machine-consumable format.

Answer (score 2):

whereis [command]

whereis ls
ls: /usr/bin/ls

Answer (score 1):

You could use [which](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman1/which.1.html) command to see the full name of an executable.
Like 'which foo' would return the full path to foo

Comment: this is yielding me onlt the utitlites present in /usr/bin. I would want to find the path of otherutilities present in other folders as well..

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the shell you use and whether the command is in your PATH or not.

Assuming you are using ksh, you can use the `whence` command in the first case. If the command is not in your path or if you want to know if alternative versions exist, you can run something like

```
find $(find / ! -local -prune -o -name "*bin" | grep bin) -type f -name ls
```

It assumes commands are in all in directories which name ends with bin, which is usually the case.